# Subdomain A record, how to proxy subdomain MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, a-record

I have a subdomain of a site, lets say `foo.example.com` which has an A record to the IP of another server, lets say `example2.com`. Ideally, I would like to have the example2's server also take care of the MX record for the `foo.example` subdomain, but I'm not sure how this would work.

I'm wondering what the options are for doing this, whether this will work:

```
example.com DNS:
    foo   A    xx.xx.xx.xx
    foo   MX   mx.example2.com

example2.com DNS:
    mx    MX   mx.thirdserver.com
```

Or could I set up a new dns zone on the `example2` server which would just handle the MX record for the `foo.example.com` domain, where any mail sent to `foo.example.com` would be handled by these mx records.

Or, alternately, should I solve this with a cname or dname record

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't have both MX records poing to mx.thirdserver.com.

Comment: because I wouldn't have continued access to the example.com DNS, and would like to just set one record and have the ability to change the MX on the second server, without requiring a change on the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegating the DNS zone for the subdomain is probably more effort than it's worth in this case.

Your first example is fine, with the exception that your MX record is badly formatted. You'll need a priority for the MX server, eg

```
    foo    A    10 mx.example2.com
```

However:

- If you have an A record for a host (foo.example.com), and you address mail to someone@foo.example,com, in the absence of any MX records delivery will be attempted to the A record. So, you don't technically need an MX record for this use case, assuming that the IP address of foo.example.com is the same as the intended MX.
- I'm not sure that chaining the MX as you have will work (eg, as your example suggests). It may do, I've never tried it. I'd strongly suggest skipping the chaining that you have, and just have the MX record for foo.example.com point strait to mx.thirdserver.com instead.

EG, if you do want the MX to ultimately be mx.thirdserver.com, just do this instead:

```
example.com DNS:
    foo    A    xx.xx.xx.xx
    foo    A    10 mx.thirdserver.com
```